# Realm ChangeListener for when objects of a type are added, not there contents changing

Tags: android, realm

Is it possible to use a Realm ChangeListener to only be notified when an RealmObject has been removed or added from a Realm, and NOT therefore be notified if an RealmObjects properties has changed?

Example: I have an app that keeps track of Trucks owned, I want the Realm to Notify me when a Truck has been added or removed but not if the Truck has just been given new tires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently that is not possible. You will get notified about all changes.
We are working fine-grained notifications that will allow this, but we do not have a timeline yet: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/989

Comment: Ok thanks Christian. Would be awesome to have, would be a paradigm shift in how code is structured around Realm

Comment: If this is not what a RealmChangeListener is used for - what's the use-case that was intended for this all-encompassing change listener?

Comment: @EddieLee looks like they have added more control over listeners now. If you follow the GitHub link in the answer you can see they have added filtering and more fine-grained notifications for RecyclerViewAdapter. However, from looking at the link I am not sure if they actually added the feature of listening to adding and removing objects.

Comment: The fine grained `RealmCollectionChangeListener` interface added in 3.0 will now give you indexes for any added or deleted objects.

Answer (score 0):

Specific change listener is now supported.

[here you go](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/4191)

[Demo](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/pull/83/files#diff-5db60168121b71f755fdff3c780e4c3dR56)